# Floating service overlay pass clicks from textView to activity

Tags: java, android

I have a floating service with a TextView. The heirarchy is as follows:

```
WindowManager
    FrameLayout
        RelativeLayout
            LinearLayout1
                ...Clickable photos....
            LinearLayout
                TextView - shows a text but I want to pass clicks from this to activity my service is floating on
```

I want the textView to pass all clicks to the activity my service is floating on  like as if this text view was never there. Right now when I press on the text view. nothing happens but I am not able to interact with the button on the activity my service is floating on.

I have tried `setOnClickable(false)` `setFocusable` and stuffs like that on the textView but none of them seems to work.

Comment: "I want the textView to pass all clicks to the activity my service is floating on like as if this text view was never there" -- fortunately, this is not possible in general, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Makes sense, Thanks @CommonsWare